# Where can I find a copy of Betrayal at House on the Hill

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Every board game store I've gone to has been sold out since last year and they don't know when they'll have it in stock again.

Online, I can't find any copies for under $150 (and I'm not ready to spend that much money on a board game).

This is a really popular game, so why is it so hard to find?

Comment: It sounds like it'll re-print in fall, so keep your eyes open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game is not currently in print; so the only copies that exist are ones that were printed before, and people have bought.

Unless you get extremely lucky, and stumble upon a game store that has a random copy sitting around that hasn't sold (not very likely at all), then the only options are to go online to places like Ebay, BGG Marketplace, Amazon, etc, where you will have to pay an increased price because of high demand.

You can follow [this thread](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1085562/price-gouging-amazon/page/1) for updates and details; it seems like they are keeping that up to date with info about a possible re-re-release (it was already re-released once).

Also, keep checking constantly online! Check Ebay and Amazon at least once a day; every once in a while you get lucky and find one for a reasonable price.

Comment: It seems like the game was recently reprinted; I've seen quite a few copies at my Friendly Local Gaming Store, Amazon, and other places.